# reading input from user

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

how to read numbers & characters from an input string containing both characters and numbers using scanf ?
For example if the input is *Fox 2 5* I get F,2,5 , if it is *Box 11 21*, I get B,11,21 , I tried using **scanf("%cox %d %d",&s,&t,&u)** but it didn't work .
I also tried **scanf("%[^\n]s",&c)** and using (char)c[0],c[4],c[6]; but with no success.

EDIT- my original method was correct, i had a glitch in dev c++ when i ran it in codeblocks it ran just fine

Comment: Where did you find "%cox"? strings are "%s"

Comment: well,if you input b9b in **scanf("b%db",&a)** a=9. and this is also true for characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you have the following format of input:

string number number\n

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
   char string[100];
   int a, b;
   scanf("%99s %d %d",string , &a, &b);
   printf("The string is:\t%s\n",string);
   printf("The first int is:\t%d\n",a);
   printf("The second int is:\t%d\n",b);
   return 0; 
}
```

If you want the numbers to be floats, you should change %d to %f.
Also note that I'm assuming that the maximum size of the string is 100 characters(change that to whatever you deem logical).

If you only want to read the first character and ignore the rest in the string, you can do this:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
   char character;
   int a, b;
   scanf("%c%*s %d %d",&character , &a, &b);
   printf("The string is:\t%s\n",character);
   printf("The first int is:\t%d\n",a);
   printf("The second int is:\t%d\n",b);
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Recommend checking the result of `scanf()`.